# How to push an install to windows clients

Tags: windows-service, uac

I need to install a windows service on many windows clients in an AD environment. I'm assuming the company has some sort of client management system installed.

The install must be silent and cause no UAC popups to appear on the clients. I have an msi install file, and I can install it with msiexec in quiet mode on my computer during testing. But do I have to write an installer that runs silently, or can I rely on msiexec to deal with that?

I'm also having trouble with the signed msi file. I have a certificate, but the install is UAC untrusted unless I install the certificate in the trusted certificate store. How is a certificate pushed to this store on the clients before the install? Or is there some other way to approach this?

How is the UAC popup dealt with generally in network based updates like this? I don't want anything to appear.

Comment: Feel free to correct me if I've misinterpreted things but what you appear to be after is a way to circumvent Windows inbuilt safety measures, rather than getting a suitable certificate and building a proper installer.

Comment: If you have an established CA in your AD Infrastructure you can use that to push trusted CA's to your clients. John was merely asking you to clarify if you wish to get around PKI or if you want to do it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an MSI file you can distribute this via Group Policy. There are plenty of tutorials:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/816102